# SSIS Convert column to rows from an excel sheet

Tags: excel, ssis

I have an excel sheet table with a structure like this:

```
+------------+-----+----------+----------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+
|    date    | Day | StoreDdg | StoreR/H | DbgCategory1Dpt1 | R/HCategory1Dpt1 | DbgCategory2Dpt1 | R/HCategory2Dpt1 | DbgCategory3Dpt1 | R/HCategory2Dpt1 | DbgDepartment1 | R/HDepartment1 | DbgCategory1Dpt2 | R/HCategory1Dpt2 | DbgCategory2Dpt2 | R/HCategory2Dpt2 | DbgCategory3Dpt2 | R/HCategory2Dpt2 | DbgDepartment2 | R/HDepartment2 |
+------------+-----+----------+----------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+
| 1-Jan-2017 | Sun |  138,894 | 133%     |              500 | 44%              |           12,420 | 146%             |                  |                  |                |         11,920 | 104%             | #DIV/0!          |           13,580 | 113%             |            9,250 | 92%              |          6,530 | 147%           |
| 2-Jan-2017 | Mon |  138,894 | 270%     |              500 | 136%             |           12,420 | 277%             |           11,920 |                  |                |                | 193%             | #DIV/0!          |           13,580 | 299%             |            9,250 | 225%             |          6,530 | 181%           |
+------------+-----+----------+----------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+
```

I would like to convert this into

```
+------------+-----+--------+-------------+---------------+---------+------+
|    date    | Day | Store  | Department  |   Category    |   Dpt   | R/H  |
+------------+-----+--------+-------------+---------------+---------+------+
| 1-Jan-2017 | Sun | Store1 | Department1 | Category1Dpt1 | 138,894 | 133% |
| 1-Jan-2017 | Sun | Store1 | Department1 | Category2Dpt1 |     500 | 44%  |
| 1-Jan-2017 | Sun | Store1 | Department1 | Category3Dpt1 |  12,420 | 146% |
| 1-Jan-2017 | Sun | Store1 | Department2 | Category1Dpt2 |  11,920 | 104% |
| 1-Jan-2017 | Sun | Store1 | Department2 | Category2Dpt2 |  13,580 | 44%  |
| 1-Jan-2017 | Sun | Store1 | Department2 | Category3Dpt2 |   9,250 | 92%  |
| 2-Jan-2017 | Mon | Store1 | Department1 | Category1Dpt1 | 138,894 | 270% |
| 2-Jan-2017 | Mon | Store1 | Department1 | Category2Dpt1 |     500 | 136% |
| 2-Jan-2017 | Mon | Store1 | Department1 | Category3Dpt1 |  12,420 | 277% |
| 2-Jan-2017 | Mon | Store1 | Department2 | Category1Dpt2 |  13,580 | 299% |
| 2-Jan-2017 | Mon | Store1 | Department2 | Category2Dpt2 |   9,250 | 225% |
| 2-Jan-2017 | Mon | Store1 | Department2 | Category3Dpt2 |   6,530 | 181% |
+------------+-----+--------+-------------+---------------+---------+------+
```

any recommendation about how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can read up on how to [ask] a question and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by taking the excel file as source. You might have to save as the excel in 2005 or 2007 format depending upon the version you are using of the visual studio if it is already in 2007 format then its good .

Now extracting the data for DbgDepartment1 and DbgDepartment2 , you may create 2 different source in the DFT. In one , you may select column which are related to DbgDepartment1 and in the second ,you may choose DbgDepartment2. You might have to use the Derived Column depending on the logic you will use further . Then you may use the Union Transformation, as the source file is the same and can load the data into the destination .Try it , you will get a solution .

Answer (score 0):

I used R statistic language to solve this issue by using data tidying packages ("tidyr", "devtools")

for more info check the link: http://garrettgman.github.io/tidying/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please refrain from link only answers. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer